# Background slide show safari

Tags: html, css, safari, css-animations, keyframe

So I created a slideshow for a homepage, and it works fine on chrome but for some reason, on safari its only showing a gradient background but no images are shown.

```
#hero-image{
    background-size:cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -moz-animation: slide 15s infinite;
    -o-animation: slide 15s infinite;
    animation: slide 15s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: slide 15s infinite; /* Safari 4.0 - 8.0 */

    #front-search-box{
        color:white;
        position:absolute;
        background-color:transparent;
    }
}



@-webkit-keyframes slide {
    0% {

        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), url("BlackBackground2.png");
    }

    50%{
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), url("BlackBackground3.png");
    }

    100%{
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), url("BlackBackground4.png");
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes slide{
    0% {
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), url("BlackBackground2.png");
    }

    50%{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), url("BlackBackground3.png");
    }

    100%{
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), url("BlackBackground4.png");
    }
}

@-o-keyframes slide{
    0% {
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), url("BlackBackground2.png");
    }

    50%{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), url("BlackBackground3.png");
    }

    100%{
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), url("BlackBackground4.png");
    }
}

@keyframes slide{
    0% {
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), url("BlackBackground2.png");
    }

    50%{
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), url("BlackBackground3.png");
    }

    100%{
        background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,1),rgba(0,0,0,0.3)), url("BlackBackground4.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this CSS or Sass ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari needs to have an default `background-image` property set in order to be able to animate it in a keyframed animation. But beware, this browser really do animate between images states (shrinks + opacity transition).

Also, if the code pasted in your question was CSS, note that it is syntactically incorrect to nest declarations like you did with `#front-search-box`.

Finally, note that if you do set the `background` property inside an animation, it will reset all the more precise rules you could have set before (e.g `background-cover`). Since here you are only changing the images, then use the `background-image` property.

Updated example without all the outdated vendor prefixed things.

```css
#hero-image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  animation: slide 15s infinite;
  /* we need to set the default here for safari */
  background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("aaa.png");
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/55/John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg/800px-John_William_Waterhouse_A_Mermaid.jpg");
  }
  50% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png");
  }
  100% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)), url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/dd/Heptagon_pavilion%2C_HK_%26_Kln_Fuk_Tak_Buddhist_Association.JPG");
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="hero-image"></div>
```

Comment: I managed to figure this out by accident, thank you for the answer :]